# Htaccess Redirect with Regular Expressions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a question regarding htaccess configuration win a PHP Project

I have this code to use redirection

```
DirectoryIndex src/client/index.php

Redirect /app/about http://localhost/app/?p=about
Redirect /app/contact http://localhost/app/?p=contact
```

Inside src/client/index.php I check the GET[p] to include the page requested.

It works... but I dont want to modify the htaccess file each time I add a new page.

I would like to implement something like this but it doesnt work, Im pretty sure I have syntax errors

```
Redirect ^/app/(.*) http://localhost/app/?p=$1
```

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch ^/app/(.*) http://localhost/app/?p=$1
```